# Nested Year/Month/Post title archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a nested post archive for my news section in wordpress theme:

```
<div class="blog-list-archive">

<?php
/**/
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date)
FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($years as $year) :
?>
<li><a href="JavaScript:void()"><?php echo $year; ?></a>

    <ul class="archive-sub-menu">
        <?    $months = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date)
        FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
        AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
        foreach($months as $month) :
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, $month); ?>">

                <?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );?></a>

            </li>

        <?php endforeach;?>

    </ul>

</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

How can I extend this to show the post titles under each month? Also I just want to fetch the posts under the 'news' category which is '13'.

Just to illustrate i need this format:

- 2013

  - January
  - post title 1
  - post title 2
  - post title 3
- 2012

  - December
  - post title 1
  - post title 2
  - post title 3
  - November
  - post title 1
  - post title 2

Answer (score 2):

Put this code beneath the code that prints the month name.

```
global $wpdb;
$sposts = $wpdb->get_col( "
                SELECT ID
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE MONTH(post_date) = '$month'
                    AND YEAR(post_date) =  '$year'
                    AND post_status = 'publish'
                    AND 'post_type' = 'post'
                ORDER BY post_date DESC" );
foreach( $sposts as $spost ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $spost ) . "'>" . get_the_title( $spost ) . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Before you do echo, typ in `if( in_category( 13, $spost ) )`, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category